# Function Duplication Due To Span & IList Lacking Common Base

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, inheritance, interface

Say I have a sorting function defined as follows:

```
public void Sort<T>(IList<T> Array)
    where T : IComparisonOperators<T, T, bool>
{
    //cool nerdy stuff
}
```

I want the function to be able to act on spans as well. For instance, if I ran the following code:

```
int[] array = new int[] {0, 3, 1, 2};
Span<int> span = new(array, 1, 2);
Sort(span);
foreach (int value in array)
    Console.WriteLine(value);
```

The console would output:

```
0
1
3
2
```

As the middle of the array would be sorted in ascending order, while the parts of the array outside the span would be left untouched.

However, `Span<T>` does not implement `IList<T>`, since `IList<T>` contains `Insert` and `RemoveAt` functions, which are not supported in `Span<T>`.

My sorting function only needs to read and write to the array, not change its length. I do not need the `Insert` and `RemoveAt` functions, and so do not want to create two copies of the exact same code for the two different types.

This leads me to my question. Do `IList<T>` and `Span<T>` implement a common interface that can be used for list accesses? If not, what would be the easiest workaround? What about `Memory<T>` and the new `Tensor<T>`?

Any information would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: If you are using an actual `List<T>` rather than `IList` then you could use `CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-7.0